Why was Moav Zoche vs Ammon
Why was Moav's mother zoche that Rus & Malchus Beis Dovid came from her?
Wasn't Ammon's mother considered more praiseworthy that she was more discreet with the paternity?

https://www.sefaria.org/Horayot.11a.2?lang=bi&with=all

@Sholom Interesting, so being first is primary?

Ammon was also zoche- Naama the wife of Solomon came from them, and she was the mother of Rechavam

@user907a that’s what it seems from that Gemara.

@Sholom Maharsha (Bava Kamma 38b) makes precisely that point: the elder daughter had the advantage of doing the "mitzvah" first, but she called her son by a name that showed a lack of honor for her father. Thus, appropriately, she had the merit of being an earlier ancestress of Beis Dovid, but lost kavod for her descendants.
